How much disk space and bandwidth does Microsoft Clarity use for mobile devices?
I'm particularly concerned about causing our customer to incur mobile data fees in low- and middle-income countries. I can't find any docs on how Clarity uses/optimizes use of disk space. I've also searched all the posts in this community.
We've kept the allowMeteredNetworkUsage of false. We'd like to keep disableOnLowEndDevices at its default of false as well. We'll be using the new React Native bits.
Questions:

How much disk space and bandwidth does Microsoft Clarity use?
What's a reasonable value for maximumDailyNetworkUsageInMB?
With allowMeteredNetworkUsage === false, will uploads only happen via wifi?

Thanks!
